# Why use Error-prone plugin in Android Studio

Tags: lint, android-studio-2.2, errorprone

I have recently installed Error-prone plugin in Android-Studio and configured the settings as explained on its website.

The plugin is working fine but I have noticed that whatever errors the Error-prone-plugin shows, at compile time, is already highlighted by the Lint tool in editor.

So I want to know why i should use Error-prone in Android-studio.
Or what are the details I don't know about Error-prone or Lint tool.